# How can I make the screen black and white?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

This is basically to transform the screen (of a laptop), into a black and white screen. I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Like a theme? Or high contrast?

Comment: @Braiam: I mean not only the windows' task bars and such, but all that I see on screen, even when navigating, the images too, or color pictures of pdfs in black and white too.

Comment: May I suggest : http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html ; there is no actual setting for what you're looking for, yet maybe you could manage some tricks with the ones related to colour management/mapping...

Comment: Any update on that - Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: For Ubuntu, there is a nice and simple answer at https://askubuntu.com/q/102440/411415

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Ubuntu, some people have had luck doing this using `Compiz Config Setting Manager`. Run it and under `Accessibility` category, you'll find `Color Filter` and `Opacity, Brightness and Saturation filters`. There you'll be get the desired effect with the available options. You can try options related to Grayscale or decrease saturation to zero to get the black and white screen effect. (I can't tell you the exact option since my current distro doesn't have Compiz Config support).

Alternatively, you could do the same by adding the following lines in your Xorg configuration:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "greyscale configuration"
    Defaultdepth 8
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 8
        Visual "GrayScale"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

[Reference answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/443346).

Keep in mind that Xorg may not start with this configuration if your display drivers do not support such a low color depth value.

Comment: And how could I then restart Xorg? Or do I have to re-start the whole system?

Answer (score 6):

On my system (ThinkPad T61 Nvidia Quadro NVS 140M), when using proprietary Nvidia driver, to transform to greyscale I use the following command:

```
nvidia-settings -a '[DPY:LVDS-0]/DigitalVibrance=-1024'
```

To return to color I use:

```
nvidia-settings -a '[DPY:LVDS-0]/DigitalVibrance=0'
```

I assigned those instructions to key combinations, so I can change my display to grayscale and color more easily.

I hope this will be some kind of inspiration to someone.

Comment: How are the key combinations set?

Comment: With `nvidia-settings` I was able to find this setting in the GUI. Couldn't figure out the name for my monitor to use the cli version though.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger: You can run `xrandr` to see the monitor.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I first had to figure out what name my display was assigned though. You can run `nvidia-settings -q all` to query all settings. If you filter properly, you will find the name of the display where you can control this attribute. For me: `nvidia-settings -q all | grep DigitalVibrance | grep -i dpy
  Attribute 'DigitalVibrance' (ubuntu-42:0[dpy:3]): -1024.`, thus I ran `nvidia-settings -a [dpy:3]/DigitalVibrance=-1024` to achive black-and-white mode.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger check out my comment to figure out the name/identifier for your monitor.

Comment: @nilon `xbindkeys`.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a greyscale effect plugin for KDE:

> **KWin Grayscale Effect**
>   Grayscale effect for KWin window manager and KDE desktop environment.

See [announcement](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9ghxzp/kwin_grayscale_effect/) and [repo](https://gitlab.com/murat.cileli/kwin-grayscale-effect).

Comment: Is there any shortcut to activate/deactivate the plugin?

Comment: there is no shortcut but this will do  the trick in a script: qdbus --literal org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.toggleEffect kwin4_effect_grayscale

Answer (score 1):

One option with hardware screen controls would be to set a custom color scheme with saturation 0.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Desaturate All](https://github.com/laerne/desaturate_all) extension. (Tested on Ubuntu 20.04)

```
git clone https://github.com/laerne/desaturate_all.git
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
mv desaturate_all "~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/desaturate_all@nicolas.brack.mail.be"
```

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> in the dialog window, then press Enter.

Enable the extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/local.

You'd need to have [GNOME Shell integration plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep/related) installed for your browser.