# How can I make the screen black and white

Tags: linux-mint, color-management

I want my screen to be black and white all the time. How can i do that ? My laptop is running on LinuxMint 20.3.

I tried to use the `Compiz Config Settings Manager` as suggested [in this U&L thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125257/how-can-i-make-the-screen-black-and-white), but I am not sure how to work with it, and I havent found any tutorial for how to use the color filter.

I also checked [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/94m7ok/grayscale_in_linux_mint/), but the answer written by xgy679 does not help because I have a intel graphic chip. The answer by danebace works only for the Cinnamon edition of Linux Mint but I am running on the Xfce edition, So I dont know where I need to put the files into (got no /Cinnamon folder).

Comment: Does this help? https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/94m7ok/grayscale_in_linux_mint/

Comment: Black and white or grayscale?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the screen black and white?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125257/how-can-i-make-the-screen-black-and-white)

Comment: @DevilaN grayscale

Comment: @DevilaN I tried to use the 'CompizConfig Settings Manager' but I am not sure how to work with it. And I havent found any tutorial for how to use the color filter

Comment: @Peregrino69 the answer written by xgy679 does not help because I have a intel graphic chip... the answer by danebace works only for the Cinnamon edition of Linux Mint but I am running on the xfce edition. So I dont know where I need to put the files into (got no /Cinnamon folder).

Comment: Dang. For the future, it's better to add new info / clarifications / answers / tests etc. directly to the question by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736586/edit) it. That way the relevant info is readily available and it reflects your current situation. For example someone may be able to point you to Compiz tutorial, or identify the appropriate folders :-) No need now, I added it for you; my edit will become visible when another member of the community approves it.

Comment: Meanwhile I found another possible solution, which uses just `xorg` configuration: https://askubuntu.com/questions/443335/how-can-ubuntu-be-made-grayscale/443346#443346s. Of course it's a good idea to back up the current config so you can restore it easily if things go south.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`vibrant-cli`](https://github.com/libvibrant/libvibrant) to change it. It worked for me on XFCE4, using a AMD Radeon card. It also seems to work with NVIDIA.